# How do I generate TypeScript definition files that are picked up automatically by VS Code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, tsconfig

I have a TypeScript project that is used in Node.js, and I have decided to add type definitions so that IntelliSense can pick it up in Visual Studio Code. On my `tsconfig.json`, I have enabled definitions to be produced alongside the compiled JS, but I don't know what other setup I need to make it so that when my project is downloaded using npm, the types appear on IntelliSense without any other setup. Anyone have any idea how this can be done? My `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "lib":["es2016","es2016.array.include","dom"],
        "noImplicitAny":false,
        "noEmitOnError":true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "declaration": true
    },
    "include": [
        "src/ts/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45753770/2270340

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `types` property in your `package.json` file to point to your definitions file, like this (assuming your declarations are in `src/ts/main.d.ts`):

```
{
   "types": "./src/ts/main.d.ts" 
}
```

See [TypeScript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html) for details.

Comment: Thanks, I had missed this on the documentation. However, the types are still not resolved if I use require() to include the library. It works perfectly well if I use import though.